# Error 1054: Column is unknown and running the same seperate query runs without problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with three `JOINS`, in which two subqueries are involved.

```
SELECT TK.id, TK.idtype,
   TK.twitter, TK.hive,
   TK.discord, TK.name,
   TK.description, TK.maxSupply,
   TK.symbol, TK.idTbGallery,
   TK.active, t1.*, t3.* FROM tb_tokensupply t1
JOIN (SELECT idToken, MAX(datetime) datetime FROM tb_tokensupply GROUP BY idToken) t2 ON t1.idToken = t2.idToken AND t1.datetime = t2.datetime
JOIN tb_tokens TK ON TK.id = t2.idToken
JOIN (SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price) FROM tb_tokensprice) t3 ON t1.idToken = t3.idToken
WHERE TK.id=84 AND TK.active = 1
```

This query gives me the following error:

> Error 1054: t3.idToken on clause is unknown.

However, the following query works:

```
SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price) from tb_tokensprice WHERE idToken = 84
```

Can anyone help to figure out why the same query inside the `JOIN` is not working?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: tb_tokensprice is a table in your DB but T3 is a temp table that has only 2 columns: MAX(price), MIN(price)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you the problem: "*t3.idToken on clause is unknown*" because you're not bringing it in your selection. Update the "*t3*" subquery as follows:

```
(SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price), idToken FROM tb_tokensprice GROUP BY idToken) t3
```

The reason why `SELECT MAX(price), MIN(price) from tb_tokensprice WHERE idToken = 84` works is because the `WHERE` clause is computed using the "*tb_tokensprice*" table.

On the other hand your bigger query just uses "*tb_tokensprice*" to compute `MAX` and `MIN`, then returns only those two fields and you'll have no reference to "*idToken*".

Comment: Thanks a lot for help me and giving context to understand what was wrong